# Is there a way to add rich comments to code?

Tags: html, css, ide, webstorm

The biggest struggle I have, when coding, is to leave good documentation. I'm often left with a need to post an illustration with diagrams and colors.

The only method I know of commenting in code, is to use text, like `// my comment`, `<!-- my comment -->` or `/* my comment */`. This leaves me scrambling, attempting to create illustrations using character symbols.

Is there a rich approach to this? Perhaps a plugin in IDE that synchronizes with online documentation. For example `// @see http://example.com/abc123` would load content from that page into an IDE in a rich format.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: You can always create a gist and add the link in comment -- I don't know how much info you are trying to convey with your code ...

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not asking for a specific plugin, rather if such a certain act is possible when coding.

Comment: @jdave - great approach. Sadly it doesn't allow rich notes, such as images.

Comment: In theory you should be able to use `@see URL` -- then you can invoke `View | External Documentation` and IDE may open that URL in a browser. At very least this is how it work for PHP code/PHPDoc with `@link` tag. For another language it may work slightly differently (as each language has own implementation/support in IDEA based IDEs). Sadly none of the IDE features/known-to-me-plugins will fetch content from external link.

Comment: @LazyOne That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I will explore the `@link` and `@see` tags